# How to override the initialized values in C# when a method is executed and page reloads

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need a functionality in C# like scrolling of images.

Images should call from database and after clicking on next.  The next 4 images should be displayed. I tried it as:

```
protected void btnleft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
     j = j - 4;
     k = k - 4;
     recomended();
}

protected void btnright_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    j = j + 4;
    k = k + 4;
    recomended();
}
```

but when these functionalities are called, the initialized values are coming in the first.

How to override the initialized values?

Comment: where and how j and k were declared and initialized?

Comment: You have to store the values of `j` and `k` in a ViewState, Session, Cookie etc.

Comment: public partial class Video : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
         int j = 1, k = 4,i;
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Use the ViewState, or pass the values on a post back or as part of the querystring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet to get you started.

```
int j = 1, k = 4;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //check if the viewstate exists, if not store default value of j
    if (ViewState["recomended"] == null)
    {
        ViewState["recomended"] = j;
    }
    else
    {
        //convert the viewstate back to an int
        j = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["recomended"]);

        //pretty obvious what this does...
        k = j + 3;
    }
}

private void recomended()
{
    //save the new value of j in the viewstate
    ViewState["recomended"] = j;

    //visualize the result
    Label1.Text = j + " " + k;
}

protected void btnleft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    j = j - 4;
    k = k - 4;
    recomended();
}

protected void btnright_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    j = j + 4;
    k = k + 4;
    recomended();
}
```

Comment: If you're going to throw up a wall of code it would be better to explain _what_ the code is doing and _why_ it works.

Comment: There are comment lines.

Comment: agin reloding the entire page it is also not working if we click on left button...

Comment: Yes it is, it will give negative values when you keep clicking left. Also if you want to keep the current values after reload you need to store it into `Session` instead. You should also research the difference between page refresh and postback.